# Textscan and Regexp Cell Data Layout

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make some logic work with some legacy matlab code.  I figured the easist thing was to make the data look the same as what the code is expecting.

I'm reading the relevant data from a CSV file, it's pretty simple -- but the format for the IDs changed from a simple number to an ID of the form [YY,ZZZZ].

As an example, the 'previous' CSV data looked like:

```
1,Simple,Data
2,More,Data-Dash-Data
3,Even,More
4,Really,More
```

The 'new' CSV data looks like:

```
[01,0001],Simple,Data
[02,1001],More,Data-Dash-Data
[03,9876],Even,More
[04,1234],Really,More
```

Previously, to read in the data, this logic was used:

```
 fid = fopen(fileName);
 data = textscan(fid,'%s%s%s%*s','Delimiter',',');
```

When this was done against the 'previous' CSV data, it returned data that look like this:

```
data =
  1×3 cell array
    {4×1 cell}    {4×1 cell}    {4×1 cell}
```

The cells then look like:

```
K>> data{:}

ans =

  4×1 cell array

    '1'
    '2'
    '3'
    '4'


ans =

  4×1 cell array

    'Simple'
    'More'
    'Even'
    'Data'


ans =

  4×1 cell array

    'Data'
    'Data-Dash-Data'
    'More'
    'Data'
```

So to handle the ID of the form [YY,ZZZZ], I had to modify the 'textscan' logic to handle the new ID format that we're using.  To do that, I'm using a regexp function:

```
fid = fopen(fileName);
rawData = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
data = regexp(rawData{1},'[ \-\/\w]*([\[][^\)\]]*[\]])?', 'match')
```

This then, after it reads in the data, gives me data that is formatted like this:

```
K>> data

data =

  4×1 cell array

    {1×3 cell}
    {1×3 cell}
    {1×3 cell}
    {1×3 cell}

K>> data{:}

ans =

  1×3 cell array

    '[01,0001]'    'Simple'    'Data'


ans =

  1×3 cell array

    '[02,1001]'    'More'    'Data-Dash-Data'


ans =

  1×3 cell array

    '[03,9876]'    'Even'    'More'


ans =

  1×3 cell array

    '[04,1234]'    'Really'    'More'
```

So you can see that it has the correct data in it -- but the data is laid out differently which is breaking on the legacy code.  So my question is how can I make the 'new' data be laid out like this as it was coming out of the 'textscan' logic:

```
data =
  1×3 cell array
    {4×1 cell}    {4×1 cell}    {4×1 cell}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fileread](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) to read in the raw file directly. Afterwards, you can use a regex which splits on either a comma, not followed by a digit, or on a carriage return.

```
c = regexp(fileread(fileName),',(?!\d)|\r\n','split');
formattedData = {c(1:3:end)',c(2:3:end)',c(3:3:end)'};

>> formattedData

formattedData =

  1×3 cell array

    {4×1 cell}    {4×1 cell}    {4×1 cell}
```